# Move array through Segue in swift 2

Tags: arrays, swift, segue

I want to pass an array of strings through segue, but my app crashes. Here is what I have in the starting ViewController:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "sendToOther") {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! OtherMinerals;

        svc.toPass1 = String(DataSet[0])  
        svc.toPass2 = String(DataSet[1])
```

and this is what I have in the receiving ViewController

```
var toPass:String! 
var toPass2:String!
```

so, I am passing every item separately through segue, but that's not elegant. I'd like to pass the whole array through, but for some reason I can't get the code right. Any genius out there to assist??

Comment: What type is `DataSet`? Add the declaration line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a `[DataSet]` variable in your second ViewController and pass your whole `DataSet` array to your second ViewController instead of the two strings:

```
//second viewcontroller:
var dataSetArray:[DataSet]

//first viewcontroller:
svc.dataSetArray = yourDataSet
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of the variable "toPass" to be [String]. If your DataSet is of the same type you can pass the array like so

```
svc.toPass = DataSet
```